# loop over columns with semi like columnnames

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have the following variable and dataframe

```
welltypes <- c("LC","HC")
qccast <- data.frame(
  LC_mean=1:10,
  HC_mean=10:1,
  BC_mean=rep(0,10)
)
```

Now I only want to see the welltypes I selected(in this case LC and HC, but it could also be different ones.)

```
for(i in 1:length(welltypes)){
qccast$welltypes[i]_mean
}
```

This does not work, I know.
But how do i loop over those columns?

And it has to happen variable wise, because welltypes is of an unkown size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `$` needs to be a column name of the first argument.  I haven't run the code, but I would expect `welltypes[i]_mean` to be a syntax error.  `$` is similar to `[[`, so you can use `paste` to create the column name string and subset via `[[`.

For example:

```
qccast[[paste(welltypes[i],"_mean",sep="")]]
```

Depending on the rest of your code, you may be able to do something like this instead.

```
for(i in paste(welltypes,"_mean",sep="")){
  qccast[[i]]
}
```

Comment: Also note you can just loop over welltypes : `for(i in welltypes) qccast[[paste(i,"mean",sep="_")]]`. If you want you can get a complete dataframe using the single [] : `qccast[paste(welltypes,"mean",sep="_")]`

Comment: no, that's nice to know, but i need them in separate data.frames

Answer (score 2):

Here's another strategy:

```
qccast[ sapply(welltypes, grep, names(qccast)) ]
   LC_mean HC_mean
1        1      10
2        2       9
3        3       8
4        4       7
5        5       6
6        6       5
7        7       4
8        8       3
9        9       2
10      10       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to access given `welltypes`

```
qccast[,paste(welltypes, '_mean', sep = "")]
```

Comment: Personally I think this is worst method of extracting columns from `data.frame`. Better use `X[select]` to get `data.frame` or `X[[select]]` which gives one column as vector. `X[,select]` gives vector or `data.frame` depends on `select` length (unless you provide `drop=TRUE` argument).

Comment: @Marek. good point. never thought about the return type difference based on length of `select`